# How to type "this" so it's correct when method is invoked on a subclass?

Tags: typescript

Let's say we add an extension method to the built-in `Object`:

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    ext<B>(f: (x: this) => B): B;
  }
}
```

The goal is to be able to use it like this:

```
"x".ext(x => x.toUpperCase())
//or
(1).ext(x => x + 1)
```

However, this [won't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1&module=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgPJoBW4pO+B8IAHqQDwBCAPgAUlAFzxhXCaQAWhAM4BKeAF5B8fkon8A3OwC+uI7m4AHFDFZgUxBawCea+ACIuLgHTdSUtRq4epCgAqmZmFADCUAogwkpKuLhAA), because the function's `x` parameter is inferred to be `Object`.

I would like it to be inferred as "`this`" (`String`/`Number` in these cases), the type of `.ext()`'s receiver.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that [it does work like you think](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=21&pln=12&pc=35#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0CmAPALgHgBUA+ACgDMAuaErKnACwEsIBKaAXiOgJaoMVTp0AJww4ArsIB20MiQbMWg6AF9UalKlCQYAIUy4MUgCYx4yNNABGHaAHIIOYYykBzO+tSopGAO5wSFgA6bBwaDi4sIKs2AHpYzGFhAHthbz9oXUCQ3HDOaCiY6HjoX1SAawggA) with your own classes/subclasses. With built ins, I think it gets a bit trickier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer to whoever reads this: do keep in mind that it's often [considered bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes) to extend native prototypes like `Object.prototype`.  Other people might be surprised to see an `ext()` method show up everywhere, or *you* might be surprised when someone else overwrites your `ext()` method with their own.  Consider using a separate function that takes the object as an extra parameter.  Okay, disclaimer over.

---

I think you might need to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to get the compiler to do this... give the method a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) so that the compiler and make the callback's argument the same type as that parameter.  Inference *should* do the rest:

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    ext<B, T>(this: T, f: (x: T) => B): B;
  }
}
```

Then this works:

```
"x".ext(x => x.toUpperCase()); // okay
(1).ext(x => x + 1) // okay
```

I don't know if it meets all your use cases but it seems to work in the cases I've tried.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChlkIAPMAHgCEAaZAFQD4AKMAC2AGcAuR+mHxZk+DAJTIAvE2TUxfagG5CAX0KEARGQ0A6cmGFSZZHWAD2AVQAOV6AGE4XCCzFjFyAPQfkZgNZwAT0IWAEYxPQpDaWQyZABqZDDPbz9AkiA)